# /usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: 3: /usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: android, cordova

guys, i hope somebody can help me!!

I'm starting to develop an cordova app this is my steps
1)cordova create hello com.hello HelloWorld
2) cd hello
3) cordova platform add android
4) cordova build android

and below the errors found

/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: 3: /usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

I'm using ubuntu16 and below my settings

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
Cordova : 7.0.1
gradle : 3.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.2.1
OS         : Linux 4.4
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.3.0 
java : 1.8.0
```

For information i testing all the versions of gradle by downloading from url
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

For me is very important to solve this...
Please somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do is to know the architecture of your computer.

If you have a 32bit architecture, you have to have version 23 of "build-tools" installed, because it is in that version where the support for 32bit architecture ends.

Font: https://www.techiediaries.com/mobiledev/build-tools24-0-2aapt-syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string/

You only delete the folder of version 24, and replace it with that of version 23.

The best thing to do is to do it from "Android Studio" and the "SDK Manager". You insure the process, since in my case I did not find the list of versions of "build-tools" to download. So I did it from "Android Studio".

[Config SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYLZh.png)